# Html Inside Javascript Script Tag Possibly Causing Error?

Tags: javascript, html

We are using a chunk of code provided by Zoho within our website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var $zoho= $zoho || {salesiq:{values:{},ready:function(){}}};var d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.defer=true;s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/COMPANY/button.ls?embedname=COMPANY";t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);<div id='zldbtnframe'></div></script>
```

Which gives an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I am wondering if the embeded html is causing the error? The line before it, which is very similar, does not have html within it, and does not cause problems.

[image]

Should this html be moved outside of the script code, or is it possible there is another error within?

Comment: That `div` should most definitely not be in the script tag.

Comment: @J.Titus that's what I was thinking as well. I just wasn't 100%. Thank you for assuring me :D

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the html within the script tag with a javascript append.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var $zoho= $zoho || {salesiq:{values:{},ready:function(){}}};var d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.defer=true;s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/COMPANY/button.ls?embedname=COMPANY";t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild("<div id='zldbtnframe'></div>");</script>
```